# Как сделать так, чтоб картинка при загрузке в медиафайлы растягивалась автоматически до нужных размеров?

Tags: wordpress

Есть проблема, надо чтоб загружаемое изображение, не зависимо от его разрешения, растягивалось после загрузки до 1200х650, как решить на wp, может плагин какой изменить?

Comment: При увеличении размера качество будет отвратное. И это не от ВП зависит.

Answer (score 1):

1. Нужно зарегистрировать нужный размер для изображений

   `add_image_size( 'need-image-size', 1200, 650, true );`
2. С помощью плагина https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/ обновить все размеры изображений. **Инструменты** -> **Regenerate Thumbnails** и синяя кнопка)
3. Теперь ты сможешь использовать этот размер в своих целях:

   `the_post_thumbnail( 'need-image-size' );`

Comment: ТС хочет УВЕЛИЧИВАТЬ размер. :)

Comment: Тогда никак....

Comment: Ну ни то, чтобы совсем "никак", но тк смысла в этом нет, то и в ВП не предусмотрено.